# How to Snap/Minimize/Maximize Window below cursor?

Tags: 20.04, window, logitech, xdotool

The default Keyboard Shortcuts in Ubuntu to maximize a window (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>) or snap it to the sides (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>) relates to the **current active window**.

While [setting up mouse gestures](https://danishshakeel.me/configure-logitech-mx-master-3-on-linux-logiops/) using [`logiops`](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops), I found out that this is a weird behavior.
I rather want to maximize/minimize/snap affect **the window below my mouse pointer** just like the scroll wheel does.

How to do this, e.g. using [`xdotool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xdotool.1.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xdotool` to get the window at the current mouse location (`getmouselocation`) and then the commands `windowminimize` or `windowactivate` + `key`.

---

I made a little script `~/bin/xdowindow` (and made it executable using `chmod +x`):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

[ "$1" = "Maximize" ] && set -- Up

eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)

case $1 in
    Minimize)
        xdotool windowminimize "$WINDOW"
        ;;
    Left|Right|Up)
        xdotool windowactivate "$WINDOW" key --clearmodifiers super+$1
        ;;
    *)
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Set custom keyboard shortcuts:

[image: Custom shortcuts]

And then use them in `logiops` setup:

```
          {
            direction: "Right";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_LEFTALT", "KEY_M" ]; // snap window to right
            }
          },
```

---

**Note:**

`xdotool` [won't work together with `wayland`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956640/equivalent-to-xdotool-for-wayland), maybe `ydotool` can be used then. I will test once I use `wayland` myself or someone else may jump in and translate the tool.

Comment: The `key` actions of `xdotool` definitely will not work on Wayland. Might be good to add a note as next month, the new LTS will default to using Wayland.

Comment: oh, didn't know that... Is there any replacement?

Comment: `ydotool`  can issue keyboard strokes and mouse clicks, but lacks window management features. A more severe Wayland problem: there is no uniform way to obtain information about the running windows: it is the compositor that implements that, so methods to achieve that are different between, Gnome Shell, Plasma and Sway.