# How can I write a program to press keys, such as Windows + D, in Wayland? (replace `xdotool` in Wayland)

Tags: keyboard, wayland, xdotool

My [show Desktop icon/script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109490/327339) doesn't work in the default Ubuntu 22.04 install, because it relies on `xdotool` to press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, and `xdotool` doesn't work in Wayland, and Ubuntu 22.04 comes with the Wayland window manager active by default, instead of X11. So, what tools can I use instead? Note: I know how to switch back to the X11 window manager now, but that's not my question. I want a tool that can press keys in Wayland.

I'm trying Python's `pynput` library too, but I can't make it work either. See my attempt here: [Stack Overflow: pynput library not working as expected in Python to press Windows + D key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76399361/4561887).

Anyway, for this question I just want a tool that can replace `xdotool` and work in Wayland, and a demo to have it press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to show the desktop.

Note: If you are also experiencing bugs in Wayland, like me, I have a few fixes and show how to switch back to X11 in Ubuntu 22.04 [in my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1470563/327339).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/956640/equivalent-to-xdotool-for-wayland  states 2 alternatives

Comment: @Rinzwind, that looks super useful. If you or I or someone can come up with some Windows + D keypress examples using some of those other tools, let's make that an answer here. It's not quite a duplicate.

Comment: Using `ydotool`, I got it! It's complicated. I'll write about it tomorrow hopefully.

Comment: I'll add an answer to my question here when I get a chance. It took me some time, but I just figured out a way with `ydotool`.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate) Q&A: [How can I install the latest ydotool 1.0.1 (keyboard automation tool working on Wayland) in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1413829/327339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Thank you very much to [@Rinzwind for pointing out the existence of `ydotool`!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470593/how-can-i-write-a-program-to-press-keys-such-as-windows-d-in-wayland-repla?noredirect=1#comment2577739_1470593)

Here's how to have `ydotool` press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. It works in both X11 *and* Wayland!

I first wrote about this on my website here: [Tutorial: Getting started with ydotool to automate key presses (or mouse movements) in Linux](https://gabrielstaples.com/ydotool-tutorial/).

For full details, see my article. Here are the key parts, copied directly from my article above:

First, build and install it:

```bash
# install dependencies
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git cmake scdoc

# build ydotool
# See: https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool#build
git clone https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool.git
cd ydotool
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..                 # takes < 1 second
time make -j "$(nproc)"  # takes < 1 second
sudo make install
# Note: the install command installs here:
#
#       -- Install configuration: ""
#       -- Installing: /usr/local/bin/ydotoold
#       -- Installing: /usr/local/bin/ydotool
#       -- Installing: /usr/lib/systemd/user/ydotool.service
#       -- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/ydotool.1
#       -- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man8/ydotoold.8

# See the man pages for help, and to prove to yourself it is installed
man ydotool   # for the main program
man ydotoold  # for the background daemon process
# help menu
ydotool -h    # for the main program
ydotoold -h   # for the background daemon process [VERY HELPFUL MENU!]

# check the version; my output is `v1.0.4-0-g57ba7d0`
ydotoold --version
```

Now, use it: have `ydotool` press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

```bash
# 1. start the `ydotoold` background daemon (`sudo -b` runs it in the
# background; see `sudo -h`).
# - It takes a couple seconds to fully start up and print "READY". Once it does
#   that, hit Enter a couple times to clear out the command line.
sudo -b ydotoold --socket-path="$HOME/.ydotool_socket" --socket-own="$(id -u):$(id -g)"

# 2. Use `ydotool`
# - Have ydotool press Windows + D once to hide all windows, then make it wait 2
#   seconds, then have it press Windows + D again to show all windows:
YDOTOOL_SOCKET="$HOME/.ydotool_socket" ydotool key 125:1 32:1 32:0 125:0; \
    sleep 2; \
    YDOTOOL_SOCKET="$HOME/.ydotool_socket" ydotool key 125:1 32:1 32:0 125:0

# 3. Additional commands you may need: to show, kill, and help

# See the `ydotoold` background running processes
ps auxf | grep ydotoold

# Kill the `ydotoold` background running processes
sudo pkill ydotoold

# View the `ydotool` main help menu, including a list of all sub-commands.
ydotool -h

# View the `ydotool` sub-command help menus. 
# - Bug ( https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool/issues/206 ): the daemon *must*
#   be running first to see these help menus!
YDOTOOL_SOCKET="$HOME/.ydotool_socket" ydotool key -h
YDOTOOL_SOCKET="$HOME/.ydotool_socket" ydotool click -h
YDOTOOL_SOCKET="$HOME/.ydotool_socket" ydotool mousemove -h
# etc. 

# Open the Linux C header file containing all available key codes that `ydotool`
# can press
gedit /usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h
```

You can also see all possible key codes in this file online: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h.

Again, for more details, see my website: [Tutorial: Getting started with ydotool to automate key presses (or mouse movements) in Linux](https://gabrielstaples.com/ydotool-tutorial/).

### See also

1. [How can I add "Show desktop" to the GNOME dash or Ubuntu Dock?](https://askubuntu.com/q/903532/327339)

   1. [@AndAC's excellent `wmctrl` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/905480/327339)
   2. [my spin on the `wmctrl` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474575/327339), relying on my eRCaGuy_dotfiles repo I have with scripts in it.
2. Q&A: [How can I install the latest ydotool 1.0.1 (keyboard automation tool working on Wayland) in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1413829/327339)

Comment: It may be good to change the instructions to use the systemd service that comes with ydotool to manage the ydotoold daemon instead of manually launching the daemon using `sudo -b` in a terminal.

Comment: @vanadium, I only learned the basics of `systemd` (meaning: the `systemctl` command) hours ago, and don't know the instructions for `ydotool`. What are they? `sudo systemctl start ydotool` and `sudo systemctl stop ydotool` or something? Is that installed as part of `sudo make install`?

Comment: It is outlined in the answer I posted about compiling ydotool: https://askubuntu.com/a/1413830/558158