# How to print the timestamp via a macro in various programs

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I am trying to create a macro to print a timestamp, similar to Google Sheets <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> shortcu or in Windows Notepad (I think it was <kbd>F5</kbd>), and I am using Settings → *Keyboard* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* → *Custom Shortcuts*. I have entered:

- *Name:* `Timestamp`
- *Command:* `date +"%a, %B %d, %Y"`
- *Shortcut:* <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Backslash</kbd>

However I cannot get it to enter the timestamp in the terminal, Google Keep, or Gedit.

Specs:

```
Host: Laptop AB  
BIOS: INSYDE Corp. 3.17 (10/27/2022)  
OS: Ubuntu bookworm/sid (jammy) x86_64  
DE: GNOME 42.9 (wayland)  
Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-39-generic  
Shell: bash 5.1.16  
WM: Mutter  
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.7GHz   
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]  
GPU Driver: i915  
Memory: 6.81 GiB / 15.39 GiB (44%)    
Disk (/): 16G / 228G (8%)  
Network: Wifi6  
Bluetooth: Intel Corp. AX210
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using a script file and `xdotool`.

1. Install `xdotool` using this command:

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
2. Create a script named `timestamp.sh` and add the following lines:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   # Get the current timestamp
   timestamp=$(date +"%a, %B %d, %Y")

   # Use xdotool to simulate typing the timestamp
   sleep 1
   xdotool type --clearmodifiers "$timestamp"
   ```
3. Now give the file the necessary permissions using this command:

   ```
   chmod +x timestamp.sh
   ```
4. Configure the shortcut by going to *Settings* → *Keyboard* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* → *Custom Shortcuts*. Give the desired name for the shortcut in the *Name* field. In the *Command* field, use the command `/path/to/the/file/timestamp.sh`. Also, add the shortcut that you want to use (I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backslash</kbd>).

   [image: custom-shortcuts]

That's it. Now you can use this shortcut to print the timestamp anywhere.

Comment: I have set it up as you described, but there is no output. I tried running in terminal each command from the script but got no output, perhaps the shebang cannot be run directly in the terminal. I have also tried giving the path as literal and logical:: /home/qrp/timestamp.sh and ~/timestamp.sh, neither path made any difference, still no output

Comment: Listed in Nemo: -rwxrwxr-x  1 qrp  qrp   177 Jan  3 12:57 timestamp.sh*

Comment: @QRP I just noticed from your "Specs" that you are using Wayland not X - you can try modifying the solution to use an [Equivalent to xdotool for Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956640/equivalent-to-xdotool-for-wayland)